# Is $ \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n ^{b_n} = e^{\lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n - 1)b_n}$ always true?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Consider $a_n$ and $b_n$ are two sequences which $\lim _{n \to \infty} a_n  = 1$ and $\lim _{n \to \infty} b_n  = \infty$ . Can we always use this formula ?

> $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n ^{b_n} = e^{\lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n - 1)b_n}$$

Also, when can we use this method for functions ?

A famous case is $a_n = 1+ \frac{1}{n}$ and $b_n = n$ . So $\lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n - 1)b_n = 1$ and $a_n ^{b^n} = e^1 = e$

Comment: The notation (of the right-hand side) is confusing. If you use two limits, make sure you let them go over different letters; as for now, what $n$ belongs to what limit?

Comment: @vrugtehagel Yes , Thank you . I edited it .

Comment: @JaideepKhare Your mean is L'Hôpital's rule  ?

Comment: @JaideepKhare No , I don't .

Comment: @JaideepKhare Okay , thank you .

Comment: This is one of those cheap tricks which works all the time (lucky!) and is a simple consequence of the standard limit $\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\log(1 + x)}{x} = 1$. And it works for functions too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this formula can always be used.

Let's take a look at it derivation.It will be clear from the derivation that where it can be used.

$$\text{let}~~L= \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n ^{b_n}$$

$$\ln L=  \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n \ln a_n$$
$$\ln L=  \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n \ln (1+(a_n-1))$$

Since $a_n \to 1 \implies a_n-1 \to 0$ therefore, we can use the fact that : $$\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\ln(1 + x)}{x}=1$$

We get

$$\ln L=  \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n \left(\frac{\ln (1+a_n-1)}{a_n-1}\right)(a_n-1)=\underbrace {\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{\ln (1+a_n-1)}{a_n-1}\right)}_{=1} \cdot  \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n(a_n-1) $$
$$ \implies \ln L=  \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n (a_n-1)$$
Hence $$L=e ^{\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n (a_n-1)}$$

Comment: You have wrote $ \ln L= \ln \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n ^{b_n}$ . Then $\ln L =  \lim_{n \to \infty} \ln a_n ^{b_n} $ . Can you explain why it is true ?

Comment: @Jaideep You have assumed the limit exists. Could you justify why/if this works if $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^{b_n} = \infty$?

Comment: @adfriedman If the limit doesn't exist, then the limit in the exponent of $e$ will also not exist

Comment: @S.H.W any finite number of operations or functions can be applied in any limit (which are well defined).Both in LHS and RHS.

Comment: This is fine if $L\ne 0.$  But if $L=0$ then  $\ln L$ does not exist, and  $b_n(a_n-1) \to -\infty$ as $n\to \infty.$  E.g. if $a_n=1-1/n$ and $b_n=n^2. $

Comment: @S.H.W "any finite number of operations or functions can be applied in any limit" That is only true in regions of continuity, and isn't generally true. Take the discrete dirac function, $f(x)=\mathbb{I}[x=0]$, which has a well-defined limit, but $$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0 \neq 1 = f(0) = f\left(\lim_{x\to 0} x\right)$$.

Comment: @adfriedman I'm agree with you . This was my problem too.

Comment: This is not rigorous and you should directly use the limit $$\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\log(1 + x)}{x}=1$$ rather than writing $\log(1 + x) \sim x$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Can you explain why if $\ln L= \ln \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n ^{b_n}$ then $\ln L =  \lim_{n \to \infty} \ln a_n ^{b_n}$ ?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes, I agree. Edited.

Comment: @S.H.W: this is a consequence of continuity of log function. Note that by definition of continuity the function symbol and the limit operation can be interchanged if the function is continuous. This is also one of the basic concepts which is routinely used in limit evaluation.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks :) Do you know it's rigorous proof? Because I use it frequently but I don't know it's exact proof.

Comment: @JaideepKhare So it is not important that $\lim _{n \to \infty} b_n  = \infty$ ?

Comment: It more a consequence of definition of continuity. Try to apply definition and let me know if you face problem.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Ok I'll try, Thanks.

Comment: @S.H.W: If $b_{n} $ tends to a finite limit then the problem is trivial and the expression $a_{n} ^{b_n} \to 1$. The trick remains valid without any problem. The essential part is that $a_{n} $ must tend to $1$.

Comment: @S.H.W Well... If $\lim_{n \to \infty}b_n$ is finite, then clearly, we can say that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n ^{b_n} =1$$ and so is : $$ e^{\lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n - 1)b_n}=e^0=1$$So, yes , $b_n$ doesn't need to tend $\infty$, it is very clear from the proof, we have no where used this fact.Only $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=1$ is must.

Comment: You can see that in your answer you have nowhere used the fact that $b_n$ tends to $\infty$ and hence it is not needed. But you have used the fact that $a_n\to 1$ and this is all that matters.