# $\lim_{x\to\infty} (2x+1)^{x-\sqrt{x^2-2}}$ equals to $1$ or $e^2$?

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} (2x+1)^{x-\sqrt{x^2-2}}$$ equals to $1$ or $e^2$?

### My Attempt

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty} (2x+1)^{x-\sqrt{x^2-2}} 
    &= e^{ \displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty} 2x(x-\sqrt{x^2-2})}\\
    &= e^{ \displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{2x(x^2-(x^2-2))}{x+\sqrt{x^2-2}}}\\
    &= e^{ \displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{4x}{x+\sqrt{x^2-2}}}\\
    &= e^{ \displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{4}{1+\sqrt{1-\frac{2}{x^2}}}}\\
    &=e^2
\end{align}

However, Mathematica Alpha gives a different result which is $1$. Which is the correct one?
If the Mathematica version is correct, how is its answer derived?

## Edit

The rule that I am using here is

$$
\lim_{x\to a} (1+f(x))^{g(x)} = e^{\lim_{x\to a} f(x)g(x)}
$$

I am not sure, the constraint for this rule is

- both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ must approach zero or
- both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ must approach infinity

Comment: I don't see the logarithm...

Comment: You may use rules if you truly know that they exist and under what conditions they can be applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$a^b = e^{b\ln a}$$ So we have $$ (2x+1)^{x-\sqrt{x^2-2}} = e^{({x-\sqrt{x^2-2}})\ln(2x+1)}$$ Also we have $$({x-\sqrt{x^2-2}})\ln(2x+1) = \frac{2\ln(2x+1)}{x+\sqrt{x^2-2}}$$Computing the limit using L'Hôpital's rule gives $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{2\ln(2x+1)}{x+\sqrt{x^2-2}} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac{4}{2x+1}}{1 + \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 -2}}}$$ Also we know that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{4}{2x+1} = 0$$ $$\lim_{x \to \infty} 1 + \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 -2}} = \lim_{x \to \infty} 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 -\frac{2}{x^2}}} = 2$$ So we conclude that $\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{({x-\sqrt{x^2-2}})\ln(2x+1)} =  e^{\lim_{x \to \infty} ({x-\sqrt{x^2-2}})\ln(2x+1)} = e^0 = 1$

Comment: @MathNewbie You have wrote $\lim_{x\to\infty} (2x+1)^{x-\sqrt{x^2-2}} = e^{ \lim_{x\to\infty} 2x(x-\sqrt{x^2-2})}$ which is clearly wrong.

Comment: How did you get this "identity"?

Comment: @MathNewbie I think you are referring to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2266709/is-lim-n-to-infty-a-n-b-n-e-lim-n-to-inftya-n-1b-n-alway).

Comment: @S.H.W In the formula you linked to, the base tends to 1, but in OP's case, they used 2x+1, which tends to infinity.

Comment: @MathNewbie No problem. Note that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n ^{b_n} = e^{\lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n - 1)b_n}$ is true when $a_n \to 1$.

Comment: @Divide1918 That's true. So it's wrong to say $\lim_{x\to\infty} (1+f(x))^{g(x)} = e^{\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)g(x)}$ in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Using equivalents when $x$ is large
$$(2x+1)\sim 2x \qquad \text{and} \qquad x-\sqrt{x^2-2} \sim \frac 1x$$

Now what is the limit of $(2x)^{\frac 1x}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible way using that $\lim_{t\to+\infty}t^{\frac 1t}=1$.

Rewrite your expression as follows:
\begin{eqnarray*} (2x+1)^{x-\sqrt{x^2-2}}
& = & \left((2x+1)^{\frac{1}{2x+1}}\right)^{(2x+1)(x-\sqrt{x^2-2})}\\
& = & \left(\underbrace{(2x+1)^{\frac{1}{2x+1}}}_{\stackrel{x\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}1}\right)^{\underbrace{\frac{2(2x+1)}{x+\sqrt{x^2-2}}}_{\stackrel{x\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}2}}\\
& \stackrel{x\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow} & 1^2 = 1
\end{eqnarray*}